# How can I rewrite an Excel formula to exclude users with an @mydomain.com in their email address?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I rewrite this Excel formula so it properly excludes users with @mydomain.com in their email address?  The formula currently counts **all** unique logins.  The formula needs to accommodate blank records between rows 2 and 100,000.

**Data sheet name "Data-User":**
Column A is the activity type
Column C contains the date
Column M contains the user's email address
Column O contains the username

**In another sheet (the report):**
B6 is the cell containing the start date of the report
C6 is the cell containing the end date of the report

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(

IF(('Data-User'!A2:A100000="ACTIVITY_LOGIN_USER")*
('Data-User'!C2:C100000>=B6)*('Data-User'!C2:C100000<=C6)*
('Data-User'!O2:O100000<>"admin")*
('Data-User'!M2:M100000<>"*@mydomain.com")>0,
MATCH('Data-User'!M2:M100000,'Data-User'!M2:M100000,0),""),

IF(('Data-User'!A2:A100000="ACTIVITY_LOGIN_USER")*
('Data-User'!C2:C100000>=B6)*('Data-User'!C2:C100000<=C6)*
('Data-User'!O2:O100000<>"admin")*
('Data-User'!M2:M100000<>"*@mydomain.com")>0,
MATCH('Data-User'!M2:M100000,'Data-User'!M2:M100000,0),"")

)>0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is replace the part where you compare M2:M100000 with mydomain.com with

```
ISERROR(SEARCH("@mydomain.com",'Data-User'!M2:M100000))
```

so if it *doesn't* find @mydomain.com in the email address it *will* be included in the count.

However this could fall over if the email address is missing, so need to add

```
len('Data-User'!M2:M100000)>0
```

as well.

So the whole formula would be

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(

IF(('Data-User'!A2:A100000="ACTIVITY_LOGIN_USER")*
('Data-User'!C2:C100000>=B6)*('Data-User'!C2:C100000<=C6)*
('Data-User'!O2:O100000<>"admin")*
ISERROR(SEARCH("@mydomain.com",'Data-User'!M2:M100000))*
(LEN('Data-User'!M2:M100000)>0) >0,
MATCH('Data-User'!M2:M100000,'Data-User'!M2:M100000,0),""),

IF(('Data-User'!A2:A100000="ACTIVITY_LOGIN_USER")*
('Data-User'!C2:C100000>=B6)*('Data-User'!C2:C100000<=C6)*
('Data-User'!O2:O100000<>"admin")*
ISERROR(SEARCH("@mydomain.com",'Data-User'!M2:M100000))*
(LEN('Data-User'!M2:M100000)>0) >0,
MATCH('Data-User'!M2:M100000,'Data-User'!M2:M100000,0),"")

)>0,1))
```